# Need to add a number of variables dynamically after user clicks on Add button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I'm working on this app where i have an input field and i want to make it in a way where in the start i have X variable but when the user clicks on an Add button, the app should add Y, Z, and so on ..
Any ideas on how to approach this efficiently?
Please help !

So here, i have an X column where the user can enter any numbers, and when the user clicks on the add button, the app will add another column and the focus will move on from the X column to the new column.

[image: screenshot of the app]

Here's the code

```
  const [xInput, setXInput] = useState(""); // input field
  const [xDisplay, setXDisplay] = useState([]); // array of number from the input field

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const tempArr = [...xDisplay];
    tempArr.push(Number(xInput));
    setXInput("");
    setXDisplay(tempArr);
  };

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
        <Input
          keyboardType="numbers-and-punctuation"
          onChangeText={setXInput}
          onSubmitEditing={handleAdd}
          value={xInput}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Button title="Calculate" onPress={() => handleCalculate()} />
        <Button title="Add" onPress={handleAdd} />
        <Button title="Reset" onPress={handleReset} />
      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Comment: why do you need to add variables? There's probably a way of achieving what you are trying to do with another better approach

Comment: Can you add some code snippet what you have tried so far?

Comment: yeah sure, give a minute. I added an image for more reference if that helps

Comment: you don't need to add variable dynamically, you just need to have an array that contains the values in each row, you can `push` to the array in your `handleAdd` function, if you plan on calculating something, just iterate over the array

Comment: @EricHasselbring yeah that's what I had in mind, I asked to get a second opinion or different approach. But thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change your state to an array of arrays, and then you can push to that to add another column, or push to each of the outer arrays to add another row.

You can then map over that array to render as many `View`s as columns you need.

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo demo where we keep track of the column in the state and on each click, add a new column:
Let `<MyCol />` is our column component.

```js
   const APP = () => {
       const [column, setColumn] = useState(<MyCol />); // initially we have one
       const handleAdd = () => {
          setColumn((oldColumn) => {
              NewColumn = [...oldColumn];
              newColumn.push(<MyCol />);
              return newColumn;
          })
       } 
       return (
           {column.map(col => col)}
           <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
       )
   }
```

Note: it's a pseudo, so it's upto you to implement this with best practice like providing unique key and etc. Moreover, you can alter the *state* structure and put your data in multiple different *state*s depending on your needs.